# Nginx rewrite .jsp extension and proxy to tomcat

Tags: nginx, proxy, tomcat, rewrite

**Incoming request**

How can i create a Nginx rewrite rule in the appriopriate server block, that takes any URL, that does not end on `.do` and add an `.jsp` extension, and than hand over the request to the proxied (Tomcat) server?

**Outgoing request**

How can i create a Nginx rewrite rule in the apprioate server block, that takes any URL received from the proxied (Tomcat) server that ends on `.jsp`, remove the `.jsp` extension, and send the response to the client?

**Test**

I tried to play around with the following

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.test.local test.local;

        location / {
                if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.jsp$) {
                        return 302 /$1;
                }
                try_files $uri.jsp @proxy;
        }

        location @proxy {
                proxy_pass http://websites/;
                include proxy_params;
        }
}
```

Nginx removes the .jsp extension when the request is received, but Nginx also sends the request to Tomcat without the .jsp extension, so tomcat does not know what to look for and returns a 404.

> I have confirmed the above by looking at both Nginx and Tomcat server
>   logs.

**The problem**

As far as i can tell, Nginx is not asking Tomcat **do you have a $uri.jsp page** but is instead asking if tomcat **has a $uri page (without .jsp extension).**

As far as i can read and understand, the try_files syntax is

```
try_files [Location[file, folder]] [fallback[file, folder, HTTP code]]
```

But the official documentation does not say (as far as i can find) how to instruct Nginx to (in this case) ask the proxy for the different files and folders to **try**, but is instead quering its own local root location for $uri.jsp and than using @proxy as fallback.

Comment: But you have a return 302 /$1 first and there the $1 is everything without the .jsp extension. So the client gets a redirect, it comes back to your server, now in the try_files, it tests if there is $uri.jsp there is not, so it sends it whole to @proxy (without the .jsp extension)

Comment: Also is Nginx mandatory here? Besides using external parts in Perl/JS/etc and their Nginx modules I am not sure you can do such proxying. You may have more luck with Apache proxying feature. But in all cases I doubt any proxy will try one url and then another in the backend, it is not really supposed to work like that you may need to revisit your whole setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you need:

```
location ^~ .jsp {
  rewrite /(.*).jsp /$1  break;
  proxy_pass         http://websites;
  proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

Instead of `return 302`, you better off rewriting the request applying the transformation you need without the redirection.

This way you have one less roundtrip from browser to server and back again.

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to why this is the solution?